# Aerospike server crashed with error "__setDR: Assertion `!”setDR ERROR”’ failed"

Tags: aerospike

I am running aerospike server on ubuntu 16.04 on aarch64 device. Server is crashing with below error when I test with aerospike_test running on the same device

```
asd: bt_code.c:345: __setDR: Assertion `!“setDR ERROR”’ failed.    
Dec 04 2017 17:09:00 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c:96) SIGABRT received, aborting Aerospike Community Edition build 3.15.0.0 os ubuntu16.04    
Dec 04 2017 17:09:00 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c:100) stacktrace: found 1 frames    
Dec 04 2017 17:09:00 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c:100) stacktrace: frame 0: ./target/Linux-aarch64/bin/asd(as_sig_handle_abort+0x58) [0x483e88]    
Makefile:70: recipe for target ‘start’ failed    
make: *** [start] Aborted
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/setdr-assertion-setdr-error-failed/4791/3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Aerospike Community Edition, which is an open source project. The repo for it is on GitHub at [aerospike/aerospike-server](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server).

As a community (as-in free) user, you should contribute to the project by opening a good bug report, or adding information to an existing, similar bug. On GitHub you do this by going to the [issues](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server/issues) page of the project. You can hit the [`New Issue`](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server/issues/new) button to open a new issue.

Please add information about your OS, kernel, the version of the server, and any other pertinent information.